# Convert column which contains array into new lines

Tags: postgresql

I do have a table with the next data

```
val
---
["a", "b", "c"]
["d", "e", "f"]
```

is there a way to select and output it into a format of

```
val
----
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a JSON array, so you can use:

```
select e.val
from the_table
   cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.val) as e(val)
```

This assumes that `val` is defined as `jsonb` (which it should be). If it's "only" `json` use `json_array_elements()` instead. If it's not even `json`, but just `text`, then cast it `val::jsonb`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `unnest` function to achieve this. Documentation can be found in array functions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-array.html

`SELECT unnest(val)` should do the job